# Where are the Data Annotations for EF6

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations

Whilst using EF6 I am having trouble finding the Data Annotation. More Specfically the Table and the Column Data Annotation

Example:

```
[Table(Schema = "Foo")]
```

or

```
[Column(TypeName = "Bar")]
```

I have installed the EF package from the NuGet Package manager and I added the `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`

However I cannot seem to find the DataAnnotations I require. Have I installed and specified the right packages and using statments ?

Comment: What version of the framework are you using? There are different DLLs for 3.5 vs 4 vs 4.5.

Comment: I'm using .Net 4.5 and EF 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are in the

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema
```

namespace